# How to set a transition each time that the text changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem that how do I set a transition to the text to appear each time I click a button using the method innerHTML to add the text.

What I did is set a transition on css but it only affects when the space is empty and I click a button for the first time and the text appears, but it does not affect when I click other button and the text changes, what I have also tried is set a .style.transition in the getElementByID in the javascript file but it does not work.

```js
var name;

function something(json) {
  name = json.data.name;
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Haz añadido " + name +
    " ,ahora elige tu cantidad";
  document.getElementById("text1").style.color = "white";
  document.getElementById("text1").style.trasition = "1s";
}
```

```css
h5#text1 {
  color: "white";
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 0 5% -20%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<form get="/page2/bisagras/cambio.html" method="post">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light bn" id="1"> 
                 <span class="dif">3/8"</span> Q2.15</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light bn" id="2"> 
                 <span class="dif">1/2"</span> Q2.90</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light bn" id="3"> 
                 <span class="dif">5/8"</span> Q3.75</button>

</form>


<div class="cant">
  <h5 id="text1"></h5> //THIS IS THE WHERE APPEARS THE TEXT
</div>
```

What I expect is each time a button is click in the HTML the text appears slowly like fade in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run example from here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sirhvd/j3yovdgx/)

```js
function show() {
  var textElement = document.getElementById("text");
  if (textElement.className) {
    textElement.className = '';
  }
  textElement.className = 'fadeOut';
  textElement.innerHTML = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  textElement.focus(); // use focus trick without setTimeOut
  textElement.className = 'fadeIn';
}
```

```css
.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -ms-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<p id='text'></p>
<button onclick='show()'>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is by using MutationObserver API to detect changes on DOM,
and also some hack to restart css animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

```js
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.target.classList.remove('fade');
    void mutation.target.offsetWidth; // restart css animation
    mutation.target.classList.add('fade');
  });
});

mutationObserver.observe(document.querySelector('.text1'), {
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

changeText = function (name) {
  document.querySelector('.text1').innerHTML = name + '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
}
```

```css
.text1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
.fade{
    animation: fade 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeText('cats')">Cats</button>
<button onclick="changeText('dogs')">Dogs</button>

<h1 class="text1">Original Text</h1>
```